# i want display only the 2nd row in the table

Tags: sql

or eg, i have table consist of 6 rows with field1,2,3,4.... then i want to
display only the 2nd row ... please help me on that...

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) SQL tables represent *unordered* set.  There is no such thing as the "2nd row in the table", unless another column specifies the ordering.

Comment: as @GordonLinoff suggested tag DBMS (i.e. MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, etc...) which u r using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OFFSET` and `FETCH`.

Using `OFFSET 1 ROWS` will start the selection from the 2nd row, and `FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY` will limit the selecion to 1 row:

```
SELECT myCol
FROM myTbl
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
```

Comment: This is also the ANSI SQL answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft `SQL Server` you could do as follow :

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY <field>) [Row_Number]
    FROM <table_name>
) a
WHERE a.Row_Number = 2;
```

Side Note :

`Row_Number` is one of these functions available in `SQL Server` that allows us to assign rankings or numbering to the rows of the result set data.